# Hide accordion on tab change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

**Problem:**

I have tabs that are powered by jQuery tabs. Inside tabs there are accordion items that expand when clicked. I'd like to hide all active(opened) accordion div's when I change to a different tab.

**Current code that manages accordion behaviour:**

```
var all_spans = $('.accordion-item-text').hide();

$('.accordion-item h3').click(function(e){
    $('.accordion-item h3').removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var thisSpan = $(this).parent().find('.accordion-item-text'),
        isShowing = thisSpan.is(":visible");

    all_spans.hide(500);
    if (!isShowing) {
        thisSpan.slideToggle();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Current code that should manage tab change and hiding all opened accordion elements:**

So, i thought that a simple click function would do it but apparently I was mistaken.

```
$('.ui-tab').click(function() {
    $('.accordion-item h3').removeClass('active');
    $('.accordion-item-text').hide(500);
});
```

This just does not work, do I have to search that exact div before? Any suggestions are welcome.

**Current HTML part:**

```
<div class="product_content">
    <div id="tabs">

      <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="#tabs-0">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">General specifications</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="tabs-0" class="tabcontent"> 

          <div class="accordion_wrap">
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h3>Accordion label</h3>
                <div class="accordion-item-text">accordion content</div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="accordion_wrap">
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h3>Accordion label</h3>
                <div class="accordion-item-text">accordion content</div>
            </div>
          </div>

      </div>

      <div id="tabs-1" class="tabcontent">                                
          <div class="accordion_wrap">
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h3>Accordion label</h3>
                <div class="accordion-item-text">accordion content</div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide your markup please

Comment: Can you please add your HTML part? so that we will get some more idea about the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found a solution for it. 
I dont know exactly why my previous function did not work but after sleeping on it i read jQuery UI documentation and found out that I can use my regular tabs fire function.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function(event, ui) {

        $('.accordion-item h3').removeClass('active');
        $('.accordion-item-text').hide(500);

    }
});
```